# RequestError: Connection lost - read ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, sql-server, azure-sql-database, knex.js, objection.js

I am new to mssql getting error while i am deploying it into my dev environment but  at local it works fine only for specific query it doesn't work

Here is my code

```
 return Order.query()
.joinEager('[shipments.shipmentQuantities.lineItem, lineItems.shipmentQuantities]')
.findById(id);
```

using nodejs with version 10 and objection 1.4.0

Here is my connection file

```
database: {
  client: 'mssql',
  connection: {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    charset: 'utf8',
    stream: true,
       options: process.env.ENABLE_DB_SSL ? {
       port: 1433,
       database: process.env.DB_NAME,
       encrypt: true,
    } : undefined,
   },
    debug: false,
  },
```

Error Details

```
RequestError: Connection lost - read ECONNRESET 
at handleError (/src/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js:519:15) 
at Connection.emit (events.js:203:15) 
at Connection.socketError (/src/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1028:14) 
at Socket.<anonymous> (/src/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:878:18) 
at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15) 
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8) 
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3) 
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

For intial db setup i am using knex
here is intial code

```
import body = require('koa-body');
import compress = require('koa-compress');
import Objection = require('objection');
import errorHandler = require('koa-json-logger-next');
import responseTime from 'koa-response-time-next/lib';
import config from './configuration';
import * as Koa from 'koa';
const Model = Objection.Model;

export default class Config {

   constructor(private app: Koa) {
   this.app = app;
 }

 public build() {
   // db setup
  const knex = require('knex')(config.database);
  Model.knex(knex);
  this.app.use((ctx: Koa.Context, next: () => Promise<any>) => {
  ctx.knex = knex;
  return next();
  });
  // return response time in X-Response-Time header
  this.app.use(responseTime());

  // HTTP compression
   this.app.use(compress({}));

  // parse request body into ctx.request.body
  this.app.use(body());

  // Global Error handling
  this.app.use(errorHandler({
  // As this is behind the api gateway, surface errors
  surfaceErrors: true,
  }));

  return config;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you able to connect with `SQL server management studio` or with any other tools for the given configuration?   Also, check if all environment variables are getting populated correctly?

Comment: Yes I&#39;m able to connect with SQL server management studio...and I am only facing the issue while this query hit at dev

Comment: is your dev on azure?

Comment: Yes dev env is on azure

Comment: Make sure encrypt property is true if DB is also on Azure

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a try to below configuration If DB instance is also on azure :

```
knex({
  client : 'mssql',
  connection: {
    database: 'mydatabase',
    server: 'myserver.database.windows.net',
    user: 'myuser',
    password: 'mypass',
    port: 1433,
    connectionTimeout: 30000,
    options: {
      encrypt: true
    }
  }
});
```

If DB instance is on azure then encrpt property has to be set true.

Source : https://github.com/knex/knex/wiki/Recipes